# Disable mousewheel debounce for swiper.js

Tags: javascript, mousewheel, swiper.js

I'm trying to create a vertically scrollable and draggable list with [swiper.js](http://idangero.us/swiper/), and I've almost reached the goal. There is only one issue left:

The mousewheel scrolling feels very laggy. After every scroll, there is a small delay before the next one is registered. Check out the behavior here:

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/20-mousewheel-control.html

This is my configuration so far:

```
this.swiper = new Swiper(this.$el, {
    direction: 'vertical',
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    grabCursor: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    mousewheelControl: true,
}
```

I haven't found a way to disable this. The only property that sounds like it could help, [`mousewheelSensitivity`](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/), does not seem to change the behavior at all.

Is this even possible or do I need to change swiper.js internals for this to work?

Comment: where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I don't remember what I did in the end though…

Comment: I was able to fix it, I went through the source code and changed the following line
  if (new window.Date().getTime() - x.mousewheel.lastScrollTime > 60)

to be a shorter timeframe (~30ms)

Comment: Ah, so it's hardcoded? That's too bad…

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, and haven't found a final answer for this, however, I noticed that adding the next options helps a little:

```
mousewheelSensitivity: 0,
mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true,
```

If you have found any other solution, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Mousewheel Methods & Properties:

```js
function disableScrolling() {
  swiper.mousewheel.disable();
}
```